# How to get data from Laravel backend and display in Vue/Nuxt frontend

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a Vue/Nuxt frontend, which functions as it should, and a Laravel backend that is connected to my database.

My problem is how to connect the two and display data from the db in my Vue page.

If I run the app using `php artisan serve` I get the correct data from the db, but I can't use Nuxt/Vue's page-transitions and component-only refresh. If I run the app using `npm run dev` I get the page-transitions and component-only refresh but the data returned from my Axios request is the HTML of the sending page.

So I'm assuming it's some kind of async issue but I'm very new to this and have no idea what to do.

Any tips or advice would be a huge help.

Axios request:

```
created() {
    const { data } = this.$axios
      .get("/items")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  },
```

I haven't included my controller, model etc. as it functions through the Laravel server so I'm assuming they're setup fine. Though, if needed I can edit them into the post.

Comment: Can you get laravel to answer to requests as you expect by using the normal browser? for example, what happens if you go to the /items page with your browser?

Comment: @FrancescoManicardi I get '404 not found'

Comment: @FrancescoManicardi actually if I use /api/items I get the json data in the browser

Comment: You are just using wrong URL to API. Set correct baseUrl in axios config and use correct url in .get() and it has to work

Comment: @FrancescoManicardi the api is prepended in my nuxt.config.js file so I don't need it with my Axios request

Comment: @lukchojnicki how do I set the correct baseUrl? I've found it here: ```axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.apiUrl```

Comment: And what You have in this apiUrl? Laravel and Api are running on different ports, so did You set it correctly? What do You see in Networks tab in browser debugger and what in correct URL for route in laravel app? If You see Vue HTML as api response it means that You are not actually fetching API (laravel) but frontend (Vue).

Comment: @lukchojnicki in nuxt.config.js - ```env: {
    apiUrl: process.env.API_URL || process.env.APP_URL + '/api',
  },```

Comment: @lukchojnicki in .env - ```APP_URL=http://localhost```

Comment: Yeah, so just set correct backend URL in API_URL. Artisan default starts at port 8000 so it will be API_URL=http://localhost:8000

Comment: @lukchojnicki changing it in .env didn't do anything and setting it directly as the axios apiUrl didn't do anything either. I have no idea why it's doing this

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the package [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). Then on the first line of nuxt.config.js:

```
require("dotenv").config()
```

And here is my axios setup in nuxt.config.js:

```
/*
   ** Axios configuration
   */
  axios: {
    // See https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#options
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
    headers: {
      common: {
        Accept: "application/json"
      }
    }
  },
```

This works fine for me. If you still can't recieve the API data, check in the network tab from the Developer Tools. Check if any request is fired and if so, check the url and possible response if there is any.

Comment: Are you running ```npm run dev``` or ```php artisan serve``` for this?

Comment: I have to seperate projects: A Laravel Project with the API and a Nuxt project. So i need to run them both seperatly. I think u should run both the commands.

Comment: All I get is this: ```Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/items' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.```

Comment: I think u need to include laravel-cors: https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Comment: Shouldn't the URL be: ```http://localhost:8000/api/items``` instead of ```http://localhost:8000/items``` ?

Comment: Did u insert the following in kernel.php:
`protected $middleware = [
        ...
        \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ];`

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://medium.com/@soonwang/vue-js-laravel-access-control-allow-origin-cb79fb81856